# Getting wrong number at array for index of object

Tags: objective-c

My array length is 32 and the song  at 28. but i am getting number in Thousends And  not satisfying the if .....([AlbumsAnsSongs sharedManager].movieNames  this is a array).
Any help would be appreciated.

```
 int number=0;
    number=(int)[[AlbumsAnsSongs sharedManager].movieNames indexOfObject:song];
  if (number< [AlbumsAnsSongs sharedManager].movieNamesPath.count)
{
   [self metadata:[[AlbumsAnsSongs sharedManager].movieNamesPath objectAtIndex:number]];
}
```

Comment: what exactly does `movieNames` contain? and what is `song`?

Comment: movie names contains list of songs names And Song Contain Song name

Comment: so `movieNames` is a string array and `song` is a string?

Comment: @AndréSlotta yah

Comment: did you set a breakpoint after the `indexOf` line and check what is inside the `number` variable?

Comment: every time it was a new number but in thousands

Comment: is it correct that you use `movieNamesPath`? shouldn't it be `movieNames`?

Comment: it not in range (WRONG)

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Do not use `int`. Do not cast the result of `indexOfObject:` to `int`. Use the proper data type of `NSInteger`. And read the documentation for `NSArray indexOfObject:`.

Comment: @rmaddy is It NSInteger Type....? IAm confusion For int,nsinteger,nsnumber..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation for `NSArray` you find the following information regarding the return type of the `indexOfObject:` method:

> If none of the objects in the array is equal to anObject, returns NSNotFound.

So the large number you are talking about may be the value for `NSNotFound` which is declared like this:

```
static const NSInteger NSNotFound = NSIntegerMax;
```

So maybe your song is not found in the array and your if block is not executed. Check for `NSNotFound` to see what is really going wrong:

```
NSInteger number = [[AlbumsAnsSongs sharedManager].movieNames indexOfObject:song];
if (number != NSNotFound) {
    if (number < [[AlbumsAnsSongs sharedManager].movieNamesPath.count {
        [self metadata:[[AlbumsAnsSongs sharedManager].movieNamesPath objectAtIndex:number]];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"could not find path for song");
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"could not find song");
}
```

Are you sure that your list **really** contains the song you are looking for?

Comment: i want get song path at index of songs name array Both Are Same references one has paths and another one has names so i have name so i need to get path of that name

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what was wrong and explain how your answer solves the problem.

Comment: @rmaddy I did. then i removed the explanation since I misunderstood the problem. readded some explanation.